# PHP: inherit from a class that implements an interface

Tags: php

I have two files, let's say a.php and b.php:

a.php:

```
require 'b.php';
interface testInterface{}
class a implements testInterface{}
```

b.php:

```
class b extends a{}
```

When I run a.php, it throws this fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'a' not found in b.php on line 2

Two considerations that make it more interesting:

- Everything works fine if I remove the `implements` clause in the class `a`.
- Everything works fine if I put the class `b` in the same file as class `a`, without including it as an external file.

I can't understand why it's throwing that error, any help really appreciated.

Comment: You require b.php, which relies on the definition of `class a`, before you define `class a`. For {reasons} it happens to work without the interface, but you should not be creating this logical carousel in the first place.

Comment: did you require a.php as well?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir I'm running a.php directly

Comment: Why is the file defining the *parent class* also importing the file with the *child class*?! Parents should not know about their children. b.php should `require_once 'a.php'` and you should be executing b.php.

Comment: learn to use autoloading

Comment: @deceze I wanted to instantiate b from a, but now I realize that's not how it should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: On the off-chance that anyone else comes across this, I just stumbled across this answer that does a far better job of explaining things: [Why can't you inherit from a not-yet-defined class which inherits from a not-yet-defined class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629004/why-cant-you-inherit-from-a-not-yet-defined-class-which-inherits-from-a-not-yet)**

The separate files aspect of this is actually irrelevant - you can reproduce the same behaviour by simply defining the classes/interfaces out of order.

I don't know nearly enough about PHP's internals to say *why* any of this happens, but if there is anything more than a very simple inheritance structure, then the classes need to be defined in order.

**This works**:

```
<?php
class b extends a {}
class a {}
```

**This does not:**

```
<?php
class c extends b {}
class b extends a {}
class a {}
```

You can cause similar weirdness when implementing interfaces, as in your question:

**Works:**

```
<?php
interface testInterface {}
class b extends a implements testInterface {}
class a {}
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
<?php
interface testInterface {}
class b extends a {}
class a implements testInterface {}
```

In short: Always declare your interfaces, classes and traits in the order in which they're used. PHP *might* be able to figure things out for you, but don't rely on it (and I suspect different versions will also behave in subtly different ways). The same conclusion was reached in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458756/does-the-order-of-class-definition-matter-in-php), posted a few years ago by Taylor Otwell, of all people.

Answer (score 1):

Put `require 'b.php';` at last. `class a` should be declared before `class b`

```
interface testInterface{}
class a implements testInterface{}
require 'b.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

In class b you are inheriting class, and you are declaring class a after the class b is included. PHP runs top to bottom. When it includes b.php then it try to execute the code written in b.php,  But at this point class a is not declared. That is why it is throwing a fatal error and stopping the further execution.

Try including the b.php after the class a is declared -

```
interface testInterface{}
class a implements testInterface{}
require 'b.php';
```