# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Username' not found in

Tags: php

I have the following code, where I want to instantiate the `class` *Username* by `$object = new Username`. The class *Username* extends to class *Database* (which is the class in the `require_once()` command). And I get the error *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Username' not found in....*. But when I change `class Username extends Database` to `class Username` (i.e., When it doesn't extend anymore to class *Database*), I get the error *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Username::some() in....*. I don't know what's my mistake..

```
<?php
require_once 'database.class.php';

if(isset($_POST['some'])){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM noti WHERE name=:name';
    $params = [
        'name' => $_POST['some']
    ];
    $object = new Username;
    $number = $object->some($sql, $params);
    if($number>0){
        echo 'Username Exists.';
    }
    else{
        echo '';
    }
}

class Username extends Database{
    public function some($sql, $params){
        return $this->num_rows($sql, $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try placing the Username class above your if statement

Comment: Can you show us your some() method in Username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your logic which attempts to instantiate `Username` is above the code which defines it. So, when you attempt to instantiate it, it is not defined - yet. Put the `class` definition **before** its instantiation.

Comment: Well then why does work when I remove `extends Database` part and give me the error _Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Username::some() in..._?

Comment: @user13491419 If you want the gritty details of exactly what's going on under the hood, I'd recommend [this answer about late binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29630034/4680018). The short version is to always declare your classes (or interfaces, etc) before referencing them, although PHP will be able to work around this in some cases (notably where there is no inheritance).